# SQL Left Join Queries Difference

Tags: mysql

[image]
tblEmployee Table Left and tblDepartment Table Right

[image]

First Query:

```
Select Name, Gender, Salary, DepartmentName
from tblEmployee
Left Join tblDepartment
On tblEmployee.departmentID = tblDepartment.Id
Where tblEmployee.departmentID IS Null;
```

Second Query:

```
Select Name, Gender, Salary, DepartmentName
from tblEmployee
Left Join tblDepartment
On tblEmployee.departmentID = tblDepartment.Id
Where tblDepartment.Id IS Null
```

The two queries I wrote above are used to display the data in the second picture (the one with only two rows). Can someone explain to me why both the queries above produce the same results? I understand why the first query works since you are simply filtering out all the records where departmentID is not equal to NULL and selecting the ones where departmentID is equal to NULL. Though for the second query I don't understand the idea behind the where clause. How does it filter out those two records in the Employee table that are NULL?

Comment: both the queries you posted seems to be exactly same. so the same result. may be you have to edit the question again posting correct second query

Comment: @parishodak Sorry about that. Just updated the question!

Comment: Hmm not sure why it removed all the tbl's before the Table names. I just added them in as well.

Comment: The two queries seems to be the same: Do you missed a 'NOT' in one of them?

Comment: @genespos The where clause in both of the queries are different. That is what I am having trouble understanding. How do those two where clauses produce the same result or that second picture I posted with two rows.

Comment: Looks like *[kudvenkat's tutorial](https://youtu.be/wW4xcQ3FFp4?t=130)*

Comment: Yeah those are the tutorials I am following.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second query, the `tblDepartment.Id` will be NULL for the last two records, because it cannot find the corresponding record in the `tblDepartment` table. Left Join will return all the rows from the first table. If it cannot find the values in the join, the values of the columns from the right table are replaced by NULL. Hence you get only last 2 records.

Comment: Quick Question. I don't think I understand completely what the On clause does. When you say On tblEmployee.departmentID = tblDepartment.Id, does that SQL code look at the values for each row in the departmentID column and ID and check to see if they match? And if they don't then what would happen?

Comment: `On tblEmployee.departmentID = tblDepartment.Id` Each record's departmentID in tblEmployee will be compared against each record's Id value in tblDepartment. If they match, they are joined. If no match is found, then the values in columns from the right table are replaced by NULL.

Comment: Ohh! That makes sense now. Thank you for clearing this up!

Comment: Also when the records are joined SQL knows to select the DepartmentName from the joined record since I specified that in my Select statement correct?

Comment: 'DepartmentName' is taken from the tblDepartment because only one table has a column by that name, and hence it is not ambiguous. Ambiguity occurs when 2 or more tables have columns that have exactly the same name. Here, since the column 'DepartmentName' is not ambiguous, it is taken from tblDepartment.

Comment: Ok got it now, Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

**First Query:**

```
Select Name, Gender, Salary, DepartmentName
from tblEmployee
Left Join tblDepartment
On tblEmployee.departmentID = tblDepartment.Id
Where tblEmployee.departmentID IS Null;
```

Will bring back results from A and B where A does not have a departmentId

So: James and Russell fit the description.

**Second query:**

```
Select Name, Gender, Salary, DepartmentName
from tblEmployee
Left Join tblDepartment
On tblEmployee.departmentID = tblDepartment.Id
Where tblDepartment.Id IS Null
```

Will bring back results from A that do not exist on B.

So: James and Russell fit the description.

[image: SQL JOINS CheatSheet]

Answer (score 1):

First query will give you results where employee table have results but with departmentid as null value.

Second query will give you results of all records from employee table those does not exist in department table.

So here both query will provide you same results.

Even you can get same results from single table without join as you are trying to get only those records where department does not match-

```
Select Name, Gender, Salary 
from tblEmployee 
where departmentID IS Null;
```

This query will be fast, department name is not included as you never get it by this query.

Comment: Ah ok that answered my second question as well. The tutorial I was following did it using joins but I did it the way you did it using no Joins and that worked as well.